# Conflict using \overset inside bold math

Tags: bold, boldmath, bm, overset

I'm trying to make a line of math symbols bold. I've been using `\boldsymbol` throughout my document to this end, but now I've stumbled with a problem. If I use `\boldsymbol{\overset{\phi}{\to}}` I get the following error code:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
>   If you really absolutely need more capacity,
>   you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

I've switched to `\bm` with the same result. I could always use `\overset{\boldsymbol{\phi}}{\boldsymbol{\to}}}`, but the problem is I have a line with *loads* of `\overset` commands, so it would be quite painful to do this every time manually.

Is there something else I can do to fix it? Thanks!

EDIT: `\boldsymbol` does indeed work, but `\bm` doesn't. Since the results aren't exactly the same with both commands, is there a way to make it work whith `\bm`?

Comment: Everything works fine for me... You might want to provide a minimum working example of your problem! :/

Comment: @Vinzza Whooops, I'm sorry. I had the package `bm` loaded twice, so even when I thought I'd removed it, it was still in effect. Thanks a lot! Removing the package did solve the problem.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to load `bm` anyhow: it's generally superior to `ambsy`.

In cases like these, adding a pair of braces is the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\bm{{\overset{\phi}{\to}}}$

$\overset{\phi}{\to}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better yet, in my opinion, is to define a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\oversetbm}[2]{\overset{\bm{#1}}{\bm{#2}}}

\begin{document}

$\oversetbm{\phi}{\to}$

$\overset{\phi}{\to}$

\end{document}
```

The reason is quite simple: compare what you get from the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\oversetbm}[2]{\overset{\bm{#1}}{\bm{#2}}}

\begin{document}

$A\oversetbm{\phi}{\to}B$

$A\bm{{\overset{\phi}{\to}}}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]